# PHP/MYSQL- How to use IN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i am add new post that time select multiple category and store in database like 48,52 into single field sub_cat_id

I am try to get value using IN but not get properly

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_listing 
WHERE status='1' and sub_cat_id IN (52)
ORDER BY tbl_listing.company_name DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

[image]

I am store value into db like below screenshot

Please help me

Comment: I'm confused. Please edit your question to be more clearer.

Comment: `sub_cat_id IN(52)` is equal to `sub_cat_id = 52`

Comment: but i am save value in to sub_cat_id like 48,52 and etc and when i am passic value like listing?sub_cat_id=52 this time not work

Comment: what is `sub_cat_id 48,52`? this is something like `sub_cat_id=48`, `sub_cat_id=52`?

Comment: What is data type of `sub_cat_id`? Are you passing a CSV value like `'48,52'` to `IN`? Example: `... and sub_cat_id  IN( '48,52' )` ?

Comment: When i am add new post that time select multiple category and store in database like 48,52

Comment: i think you should check status=='1'

Comment: @nkuldip: My question is if `48,52` is stored into a column in a single row? Or multiple rows like `48` in a row and `52` in another row?

Comment: @Ravinder yes single,using implode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing `48,52` as comma separated numbers as a string to `IN` then search is not performed correctly. You have to use `FIND_IN_SET` with column and the CSV value.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_listing 
WHERE status='1' 
  and ( FIND_INSET( 48, sub_cat_id ) > 0
        OR FIND_INSET( 52, sub_cat_id ) > 0 )
ORDER BY 
  tbl_listing.company_name DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

**Refer to**:

- **MySQL**: [***FIND_IN_SET( str, strlist )***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set): Return the index position of the first argument within the second argument

Comment: but not only these two id , i am passing dynamic id, like ?sub_cat_id=52

Comment: Yes, you can use the same with `FIND_IN_SET` too. See my example. `FIND_IN_SET( 52, sub_cat_id )`.

Comment: It will be converted and checked like `find_in_set( 52, '48,52' )` and returns a value `2`, greater than `0` means, the value is found.

Comment: And even if a single value `53` is stored in the column, you can run a `find_in_set( 53, sub_cat_id )`. It will become, `find_in_set(53, 53)` while comparing and will return a value `1` > `0` means matched entry found.

Comment: this find_in_set( 53, sub_cat_id ) useful, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_listing WHERE status=='1' and sub_cat_id IN (48,52) ORDER BY  
 tbl_listing.company_name DESC LIMIT 0, 15;
```

Comment: No reason to add single quotes to a integer values

Answer (score 0):

try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_listing 
WHERE status='1' and (sub_cat_id like ('%48,') or sub_cat_id like ('%52,'))
ORDER BY tbl_listing.company_name DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```